# How do you design python filter function to be able to sort using addition attribute?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating different filters as part of my python library. I want each filter to be a function in a python module.

```
def filterB(num):
    return num == 'B'

def filterA(str):
    return str == 'A'
```

Each of these filter can be imported and added to the list .

```
import filters

my_list = [filters.filterA, filters.filterB]
```

Now , all these can be applied as ifilter to my list.

```
my_list = ['A', 'B' , 'C' , 'D']

def nFilter(filters, my_list):
    for f in filters:
        my_list = ifilter(f, my_list)
    return my_list
```

Now, I also want each of these filter to have an order number so filter can be applied according to specific order. How would I achieve this because ifilter only takes function.

P.S. I have considered creating abstract filter class and interfacing it to my specific filter class. I am just looking for better design ways to solve this problem? So any opinion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: Make your filters list contain tuples of , and iterate over them in a sorted way.

```
import filters

filter_list = [(2, filters.filterA), (1, filters.filterB)]

data_list = ['A', 'B' , 'C' , 'D']

def nFilter(filters, my_list):
    for _, f in sorted(filters):
        my_list = ifilter(f, my_list)
    return my_list  # or list(my_list) if you actually want a list
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that pretty much works. Do you think there is better design approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Depends... you could make the filter functions actually filter, so you can just write `filterB(filterA(my_list))`, but I guess that depends on how many of them you have. If you have lots of data in your data_list (and you are first aggregating the list to later filter it), I'd consider filtering the data as you're reading it in (from whereever that is).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I do have a lot of filters. Is there a way to enclose that order number inside the filter. Order number will be only be set once and each filter will be dynamically applied based on command line input from user. So, I wanted order number to self contained in the filter itself.

Comment: Sure, you can just do `filterA.order = 4`, for example, and then call sorted with `key=lambda x: x.order`.

Comment: Aha, function attributes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I didn't read your previous comment about filtering data as I receive it. I am getting structured data from a API. So, I think I cannot filter it as I am receiving them

Comment: If you're receiving them in a single chunk basically as a list already, then you're right, yes. If the API makes you perform several requests to get more and more data, then it would make sense.